# Regex/matching engine with completely overlapping results and "cursor" manipulation

Tags: python, regex, algorithm, parsing, markup

I'm looking for something somewhat similar to a regex engine but wich allows for completely overlapping results and allows manipulation of the internal "cursor" while the engine is returning matches.

**The normal regex way:**

Say you have a normal regex with various "alternatives": `item1|item2|item3`, and you use either `findall` or `finditer` to get all matches. At a certain position in the input string, the engine may match any of those alternatives. Once found, the cursor is advanced to the index right after the end of the match and it continues to look for any of the alternatives. Even if two or more of those alternatives might have matched the string at the initial cursor's position, only one is returned:

```
import re
input_string = 'foobar'
compiled = re.compile('foobar|foo|bar')
compiled.findall(input_string)

# 'foobar'
```

**What I want (1):**

I want them all to be returned. Like so:

```
import muchneededregexthing
input_string = 'foobar'
compiled = muchneededregexthing.compile('foobar|foo|bar')
searcher = compiled.create_searcher(input_string)
while not searcher.reached_end():
    match = searcher.search() # increments searcher's internal cursor 
                              # to after the end of the match
    print(match.string, match.span())

# foobar (0,6)
# foo (0,3)
# bar (3,6)
```

**What I also want (2):**

I want to be able to modify the searcher's cursor, so that I can manipulate the results according to what happens at runtime ('foobar' is matched, and 'foo' and 'bar' separately don't matter).

```
import muchneededregexthing
input_string = 'foobarkitten'
compiled = muchneededregexthing.compile('foobar|foo|bar|kitten')
searcher = compiled.create_searcher(input_string)
while not searcher.reached_end():
    match = searcher.search() # increments searcher's internal cursor 
                              # to after the end of the match
    print(match.string, match.span())
    if match.string == 'foobar':
        searcher.advance_cursor(match.end())

# foobar (0,6)
# kitten (6,12)
```

**What I cannot use (most probably):**

- `str.find`: I need the regex thing for a markup (markdown/wiki/etc) parser. At any time, many different elements may have to be looked for. Using `str.find` I'd need to search the whole document with every element that the markup supports. The language is too complex to subdivide the document into chunks like a "header chunk", "paragraph chunk", etc.
- `re`: Unless re magically supports what I need, I cannot use it for the following reason: regexes are limited, you can't match anything you like. Yet their properties are useful for cases like mine. I plan on matching in two stages: the regex provides a possible match for an element. A smart function/method is then consulted on whether the *possible* match is a *good* match. If so, great, advance cursor. If not, screw the `foobar` and give `foo` and `bar` a chance on their own.

Ideas are very welcome. I'm fairly certain I need said features. My best idea so far is to write my own `muchneededregexthing` module with support for most of the regex syntax in C/C++, so don't fear that I will disregard your idea as far-fetched.

**Edit 1: request for example of markup**:

Markup elements, and therefore the tokens that need to be matched, are defined and brought in by means of plugins. Therefore, the framework does not contain any markup in itself. I could simply match a plugin's token with a regex and be done with it, but I want to at least explore the options and try to allow a greater range of markup tokens than what one would be able to support with a regex. For example, how would one match `string:number` if their relation would be that the number should be some numerical representation of the string? `a:0` is a valid token, but `a:1` is not. `b:1` is, however, and so is `bc:28` (1*26 + 2*1).

For this example, the plugin could provide a regex such as `([a-z]{1,5})([0-9]{1,5})`. The algorithm would then pass a match to a special function that calculates the numerical value of the first group and compares that to the value of the second group. If those values match, than plugin will handle this part of the document. If not, it returns and an attempt is made to have another plugin handle this index in the document.

Comment: The default behavior of overlapped matching is to advance the cursor a single position after each match. If it is not allowed to advance at least a single position, it enters an endless loop. The regex is fixed. Example `(?=(o+|foo))` on string `fooooo` finds 5 matches. Also, a single character exists at a position at a time, so only the regex can be variable. Ie. _item_`X` can only be _X_ and never Y. But, the regex is fixed in a state, so it can  never vary. Thus, the advance of the position.

Comment: You could use multiple regexes, to scan a single position though. But you have to control that by setting the regex and setting a position in a string. This is a single action.

Comment: Can you give an example of your markdown? It can probably be solved by regex or a recursive parser.

Comment: As Jamie Zawinski famously said, *Some people, when confronted with a problem, think "I know, I'll use regular expressions." Now they have two problems.* Any kind of markup parsing should be done with a real parser.  Trust me on this - you'll realize the truth of it the second you try to implement a verbatim section in which you don't want markup converted.

Comment: @btilly I agree, therefore the framework (it's a framework) has a "real" (recursive descend) parser. The regex-like part is purely meant to allow people to easily write plugins (which contain custom markup elements).

Comment: @fafl I can, I'll edit my question tomorrow to include a more concrete explenation of what I have in mind. It might become quite a read though.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For those future wanderers out there who seek answers to this question: I came across [hyperscan](https://github.com/intel/hyperscan) recently which does exactly what I was looking for. It's in C, but there is a [Python port](https://pypi.org/project/hyperscan/) for it (I didn't test the port, but the native C version works very well).

While most regex engines will match only one subpattern on a given offset in the input string, Hyperscan will report all subpatterns that matched for each offset. See also [hyperscan semantics](http://intel.github.io/hyperscan/dev-reference/compilation.html#semantics).

Answer (score 0):

You can easily implement this with pure Python IF you are guaranteed that there won't be two different patterns matching at the same spot with the same length.

If `pattern` is a compiled regex, then `pattern.search(str, start)` will look for matches starting at `start` and `pattern.search(str, start, length)` will look for matches starting at `start` of length at most `length`.

So do a search.  Advance to where it matched.  Check whether it is wanted.  If not, then decide to throw it away.  Do another search at the same point with the same pattern and a shorter length.  If that doesn't match, or matches farther along, advance your cursor.

Comment: Fair point, but there's no guarantee that those patterns will all have different lengths. Also, this would impose order restrictions (longest pattern first), whereas I'd rather order the patterns according to precedence of their element (a heading has a higher precedence than a paragraph, hence the heading pattern would be first).